# Does LiveData retrieved from the Room Database update automatically?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a method in my Interface that retrieves all records from my Room Database as a LiveData List. My method is as follows:

```
 @Query("SELECT *FROM task_table ORDER BY taskId DESC")
    fun getAll():LiveData<List<Task>>
```

I have the following code in my ViewModel class:

```
val tasks:LiveData<List<Task>> = taskDao.getAll()
```

Also I've got an Observer setup in my Fragment as follows:

```
//After some other code and code to create an instance of the ViewModel
viewModel.tasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.data = it
            }
        })
```

I'm a bit confused with LiveData. When I add a new record to my Room Database, my LiveData<List> updates on it's own without me having to call the

getAll() method. When you have LiveData, does the Android OS updates this List when you add/delete/update a record in the Database? Thanks.

Comment: `When I add a new record to my Room Database, my LiveData<List> updates on its own`, that's how `LiveData` works. It propagates the new changes if you have an active observer on that LiveData.

Answer (score 2):

When you observe LiveData, you will get the new data as long as the viewLifeCycleOwner is in one of the following states: `Lifecycle.State.STARTED` or `Lifecycle.State.RESUMED`. So your assumption is correct.

Please read more about observing LiveData [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects).

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM Brands order by _id")
   fun getAll(): List<BrandEntity>
   ```
2. ```
   class BrandViewModel : ViewModel() {
       private val _list = MutableLiveData<List<BrandEntity>>().apply {
           value = AppDatabase.get().brandsDao().getAll()
       }
       val list: LiveData<List<BrandEntity>> = _list
   }
   ```
3. ```
   val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ProductsViewModel::class.java]
   viewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   }
   ```